# passing parameters into function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to javascript and I hope to get some help simplifying the code.

I have two `div` box that contains 3 images each. Each div box displays an image by default (no. 1 and 4) and the mouse hover toggle a change in image (independently). See http://jsfiddle.net/hdaq9se5/6/.

The following code works just right but I am hoping to get some help simplifying the code, e.g. modify the `animation` function such that it takes the `class` of the `div` box as input.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#image_two, #image_three, #image_five, #image_six").hide();
    $(".image_rollover").hover(function () {
       animation()
    });

     $(".image_rollover2").hover(function () {
       animation2()
    });
});

function animation() {
    var $curr=$(".image_rollover img:visible");
    var $next=$curr.next();    

    if($next.size()==0) $next=$(".image_rollover img:first");

    $next.show();
    $curr.hide();
}

function animation2() {
    var $curr=$(".image_rollover2 img:visible");
    var $next=$curr.next();    

    if($next.size()==0) $next=$(".image_rollover2 img:first");

    $next.show();
    $curr.hide();
}
```

Comment: It seems off topic here on SO. There is a Code Review Stack Exchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a code review, not how to solve a problem. ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Code review questions aren't inherently off-topic *because* they're code-review questions; they're off-topic because they're often too broad. However, OP seems to have a pretty specific ask in this case: *"modify the animation function such that it takes the class of the div box as input"*

Comment: That said, the question really needs the HTML. Maybe you can use a common class instead of unique. Are there more than one `.image_rollover` and `.image_rollover2` on the page? Please include a reproducible example in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I'll be more mindful in posting questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

Using jquery, `this` is in most places (almost everywhere) the current Element. Like the Element that dispatched an event, ...

knowing this you don't need to pass any classes into `animation`, jquery already provides you with all you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image_box img").not(":first-child").hide();
  $(".image_box").hover(animation);
});

function animation() {
  var $curr = $("img:visible", this);
  var $next = $curr.next();

  if ($next.length === 0) {
    $next = $("img:first", this);
  }

  $next.show();
  $curr.hide();
}
```

```css
.image_box {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 130px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image_rollover image_box">
  <img id="image_one" src="http://placehold.it/130x80&text=1">
  <img id="image_two" src="http://placehold.it/130x80&text=2">
  <img id="image_three" src="http://placehold.it/130x80&text=3">
</div>

<div class="image_rollover2 image_box">
  <img id="image_four" src="http://placehold.it/130x80&text=4">
  <img id="image_five" src="http://placehold.it/130x80&text=5">
  <img id="image_six" src="http://placehold.it/130x80&text=6">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. This is a great example I can learn from. Thanks!